# OS user authentication in a node.js app on Linux

Tags: node.js, authentication

Our company currently has a Linux daemon which handles authentication using both OS user/password and an application-specific user/password.  I am in the process of reimplementing this daemon as a node.js web service.

**How can I check OS-level credentials in a node app?**  (I know there will be some who will say we simply shouldn't use OS authentication, but it is a hard requirement for this product that I do it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally possible, but you should use authorization services like LDAP or Kerberos to achieve this goal.

Add the client functionality to your application.

**Joyent LDAP client (ldapjs)**

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://127.0.0.1:1389'
});
```

documentation: [ldapjs](http://ldapjs.org/client.html)

**Passport Kerberos (passport-kerberos)**

```
var REALM="EXAMPLE.COM"

passport.use(new KerberosStrategy(
  function(username, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user, REALM);
    });
  }
));
```

documentation: [passport-kerberos](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/)

You must run either a Kerberos or LDAP server providing this basic authentication service.

[***Update based on comment #1***]

These are "de facto" standards nowadays, you may use other services like FreeIPA (node-freeipa) but LDAP would be the suggested path. In my experience, OpenLDAP is really easy to use.

Otherwise, you will need to develop a custom PAM integration, like node-authenticate-pam project.

```
var pam = require('authenticate-pam');
pam.authenticate('myusername', 'mysecretpassword', function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log("Authenticated!");
    }
  });
```

repo: [authenticate-pam](https://github.com/Rush/node-authenticate-pam)

Note: This project is not being maintained anymore.

Comment: You say that I "should" use authorization services like LDAP or Kerberos.  Because that's basically the only way, or are there other ways without using those services that you did not mention?  I ask because based on past experiencing dealing with these services, I'd prefer to not use them if at all possible.  LDAP and Kerberos are practically the poster children of annoying-to-set-up-and-maintain services.

Comment: Hi Bill, I've updated my answer based on your recent comment.